# Writing to a buffer is slow in opencl

Tags: c, opencl

I have the following buffer:

```
    int nbytes = 256*256*4;
    uint8_t buffer_window[nbytes;
```

I allocate it on host like above. Now I'm using the following for creating it

```
  a_memobj = CL_CHECK2(clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, nbytes, (void*)&buffer_window[0], &_err));
```

and I enqeue a 2D Kernel normally on 2D framebuffer:

```
  global_size[0] = 256;
  global_size[1] = 256;
  

  auto time_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  CL_CHECK(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));
  CL_CHECK(clFinish(commandQueue));
```

In the kernel whenever I write data to that buffer, it executes very slow, but when I remove any writing to that buffer, the kernel executes very fast.

Follow up Kernel

```
__kernel void sendImageToPBO(__global uchar4* dst_buffer, __global struct Triangle_* triangles, int triCount)

{
    
size_t px = get_global_id(0); // triCount
size_t py = get_global_id(1); // triCount
int width = 800;
int height = 800;

float3 v0Raster = (float3)(triangles[px].v[0].pos[0], triangles[px].v[0].pos[1], triangles[px].v[0].pos[2]);
float3 v1Raster = (float3)(triangles[px].v[1].pos[0], triangles[px].v[1].pos[1], triangles[px].v[1].pos[2]);
float3 v2Raster = (float3)(triangles[px].v[2].pos[0], triangles[px].v[2].pos[1], triangles[px].v[2].pos[2]);
float xmin = min3(v0Raster.x, v1Raster.x, v2Raster.x);
float ymin = min3(v0Raster.y, v1Raster.y, v2Raster.y);
float xmax = max3(v0Raster.x, v1Raster.x, v2Raster.x);
float ymax = max3(v0Raster.y, v1Raster.y, v2Raster.y);
float slope = (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin);
int dp, y;
bool discard_;
float ratio;
for (int x = round(xmin); x <= round(xmax); x++) {
    y = slope * (x - round(xmin) + ymin);
    ratio = (x - round(xmin) / (round(xmax) - round(xmin)));
    discard_ = false;

    int flatIdx = width - x + (height - y) * width;
    if (y < 0 || y > height || x < 0 || x > width) {
        discard_ = true;
    }
    if (!discard_) {


        fragments[flatIdx].col[0] = 1.0f;
        fragments[flatIdx].col[1] = 0;
        fragments[flatIdx].col[2] = 0;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the kernel does not write any data/results to a buffer in global memory, the compiler throws out all the code and you essentially get an empty kernel with zero execution time.

Global range / buffer size in your case is very small. Typically, you want at least several million threads to get full saturation and good performance. Otherwise, initial kernel compile time, PCIe data transfer and and kernel call latency might dominate, rather than kernel execution time.

Comment: The problem is I'm writing a 2D framebuffer ((OpenCL Software Rasterizer), I have tried to set global range more than the framebuffer width and height, the kernel runs slower

Comment: In this case, make one thread per pixel, or if you have an array of triangles, one thread per triangle and solve visibility via z-buffer. Sometimes global range cannot be large and that is fine then.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I configure one thread per triangle, I have an array of triangles, but I'm newbie in OpenCL, so I would like to know how to configure one thread per pixel.. If you want I can show you the kernel its very simple

Comment: I posted the kernel for follow up, Danke Schoen

Comment: I wish I get an answer :) looking every an hour to see if you commented

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing. You parallelize the kernel over pixels, but then `index<triCount` does not make sense, and then rasterize one triangle per pixel? Try this: for each triangle, color all pixels on the image with bresenham algorithm. Then do all triangles in parallel with OpenCL. Your `index=get_global_id(0);` should be between `0` and `triCount`.

Comment: Can you show me please pseudo code, I'm very confused with your approach, would be very helpful

Comment: If I color all the pixels on the mage with bresnham, I should run a 2D Kernel, before that for each triangle, use berensham render into framebuffer <-- 2D with frameWidth* Height, I'm confused fully

Comment: I have edited according to your commented the post, it draws random lines... but good FPS